# Search Filter not working in Elastic Search PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Stored a new index by the following code.

```
$data = array(
    array("Name"=>"Norman","Email"=>"in.dolor@vulputatemauris.ca","Created"=>"2019-12-29 10:28:03","Modified"=>"2020-11-07 01:45:23"),
    array("Name"=>"Drake","Email"=>"posuere@sedorcilobortis.co.uk","Created"=>"2020-11-08 14:37:00","Modified"=>"2019-08-10 06:42:07"),
    array("Name"=>"Wynne","Email"=>"ligula.Donec@adipiscingenim.net","Created"=>"2019-05-19 23:30:42","Modified"=>"2019-06-09 08:13:58"),
    array("Name"=>"Kirsten","Email"=>"lobortis@Suspendisseeleifend.net","Created"=>"2020-01-09 23:34:19","Modified"=>"2020-04-16 10:23:07"),
    array("Name"=>"Ainsley","Email"=>"elit.dictum.eu@Quisquelibero.org","Created"=>"2019-01-22 18:14:39","Modified"=>"2019-09-02 18:44:30"),
    array("Name"=>"Walker","Email"=>"ullamcorper@luctussitamet.org","Created"=>"2020-11-05 23:04:46","Modified"=>"2020-01-03 09:29:36"),
    array("Name"=>"Evelyn","Email"=>"amet.metus.Aliquam@dui.org","Created"=>"2020-06-28 13:23:09","Modified"=>"2019-04-02 05:41:33"),
    array("Name"=>"James","Email"=>"amet.risus@nullaCras.net","Created"=>"2020-04-20 10:15:54","Modified"=>"2020-07-22 12:04:49"),
    array("Name"=>"Melvin","Email"=>"nec.eleifend.non@elit.edu","Created"=>"2020-03-07 05:19:53","Modified"=>"2018-12-30 19:33:29"),
);

$hosts = ['http://localhost:9200'];
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();

$params = [
    'index' => 'dummy_data',
    'id'    => 'my_id',
    'body'  => ['data' => $data]
];

$response = $client->index($params);
```

Trying to search the first record by the following:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'dummy_data',
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [ 'match' => [ 'data.Name' => 'Norman' ] ],
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$results = $client->search($params);
```

The issue is it's returning all the records where the query is matching with only the first one.

Please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing you are using the official Elasticsearch-PHP library. In that case it looks like you are indexing all provided data as exactly 1 document with the id being 'my_id'. That is why you get the the entire dataset back when your search matches.

If you want to index multiple documents at the same time, you should look at the [bulk_index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/indexing_documents.html#_bulk_indexing) endpoint. 
Here is the official example for reference:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $params['body'][] = [
        'index' => [
            '_index' => 'my_index',
        ]
    ];

    $params['body'][] = [
        'my_field'     => 'my_value',
        'second_field' => 'some more values'
    ];
}

$responses = $client->bulk($params);
```